# How to distinguish if company is using first or third party payment processor. Mastercard transaction

Tags: credit-card, payment

I was the victim of a scam and fraud where a service was not provided. I have had information returned from the credit card company as part of the dispute. is anyone able to acertain or deduce from this is it was a third party of first party payment platform? Can I post the screenshots on here?

Comment: Third parties like PayPal or Venmo typically show up in the transaction's company name, and it shouldn't really matter for a chargeback dispute anyways.

Comment: I have a representment from Mastercard, I'm convinced this is first party. It comes off as Card Acceptor Name V.P.P. INTERNATIONAL, therefore section 75 protections should apply which the bank did not offer me

Comment: Have you called them and said "I'd like a refund under section 75"? "Did not offer" and "refused to honor" are not the same thing.

Comment: Are you asking whether the merchant of record is different from the company that was supposed to provide you with services? "I have a representment from Mastercard," Mastercard doesn't make representments. The acquiring bank makes a representment on behalf of the merchant.

Comment: So just to expand on this the creditor have used mastercard chargeback, this is more convenient for this bank as they are charging back directly to the opposite parties bank. Why did they just not iniate with section 75? In other words section 75 makes me creditor liable as well. However this is not the case if the payment processing from the merchant was 'third party' e.g. PayPal How would I work out if payment processing for the card is first party or third party?